# Silverlight Datagrid how to explicit bind DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, datagrid

Setting Binding to EXPLICIT in a textbox can be triggered by calling the following while passing the textbox name:

```
    private void UpdateBinding(TextBox textBox)
    {
        BindingExpression be = (textBox).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();
    }
```

How can I trigger an EXPLICIT binding in a Silverlight DataGrid DataGridTextColumn please?

Comment: Do you want to Raise PropertyChanged event ?

Comment: I need to apply **Explicit** binding but for a DataGridTextColumn instead of Textbox.  I know how to explicit binding Textbox as I pasted the UpdateBinding function above, but what is the equivalent for DataGridTextColumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your DataGridTextColumn to be a DataGridTemplateColumn with a DataTemplate containing a borderless TextBox.

```
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding}" BorderThickness="0" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

I also like to call my UpdateSource using a Behavior as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253695/workaround-for-updatesourcetrigger-lostfocus-on-silverlight-datagrid)